# How to add RRP(recommended retail price) to Prestashop 1.7.1

Tags: web, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to add a RRP(recommended retail price) section on all products from my Prestashop 1.7.1 shop. I have added another column  to the product database but I cannot figure out how to modify it in the Back Office and then show it Front Office.

Answer (score 0):

1. update the object in classes/Product.php

-Add a public var $pricerrp;

-Add a field in definition: 
 (for example:)

'pricerrp' =>  array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isPrice', 'required' => true),

2. Go to  src/PrestashopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product and add your new field where you want. (In ps 1.7 AdminProduct views are loaded with twig)

I think your new field will be autosaved, if not go to controller/AdminProductsController and update the `postprocess()`

Go to tpl product page and display it {$product.pricerrp}

Comment: Could you please explain me how do I add a new field in src/PrestashopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product? I am new to Prestashop development so I need more details :D